# MongoDB - Add structured properties during $group stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data with the following structure:

```
{
    name: "xyz",
    numericProperty: 28
}
```

I want to do an aggregation group stage that gives me a structure of the shape:

```
{
    _id: "xyz",
    name: "xyz",
    numericProperty: {
        min: minvalue,
        max: maxvalue,
        avg: avgvalue
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
{
    "$group":{
        "_id":"$name",
        "name":{"$first":"$name"},
        "numericProperty": {
            "min": {"$min":"$numericProperty"},
            "max": {"$min":"$numericProperty"},
            "avg": {"$min":"$numericProperty"}
        }
    }
}
```

which gives me the error:

> The field 'numericProperty' must be an accumulator object

This led me to try (And I see now that `$addFields` is not an accumulator object, but its own pipeline stage):

```
{
    "$group":{
        "_id":"$name",
        "name":{"$first":"$name"},
        "numericProperty": {"$addFields":[
            "min": {"$min":"$numericProperty"},
            "max": {"$min":"$numericProperty"},
            "avg": {"$min":"$numericProperty"}]

        }
    }
}
```

Which gives me the error:

> The $addFields accumulator is a unary operator

And I have tried:

```
{
    "$group":{
        "_id":"$name",
        "name":{"$first":"$name"},
        "numericProperty.min": {"$min":"$numericProperty"}
        "numericProperty.max": {"$min":"$numericProperty"}
        "numericProperty.avg": {"$min":"$numericProperty"}
    }
}
```

which gives me the error:

> The field name 'numericProperty.min' cannot contain '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$addFields` is not an accumulator operator. You may check the [accumulator operator list](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator).

Instead, the easier way will be adding the `$project` stage to display `numericProperty` as an object document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "min": {
        "$min": "$numericProperty"
      },
      "max": {
        "$max": "$numericProperty"
      },
      "avg": {
        "$avg": "$numericProperty"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      numericProperty: {
        min: "$min",
        max: "$max",
        avg: "$avg"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e0OiDuVaUlr)

---

Without `$project` stage, you need dual `$group` stages with [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#mongodb-expression-exp.-mergeObjects).

> $mergeObjects overwrites the field values as it merges the documents.
> If documents to merge include the same field name, the field, in the
> resulting document, has the value from the last document merged for
> the field.

**Use the `$mergeObjects` in first/only one `$group` stage, these `$min`, `$max`, `$avg` will not work correctly.** The `$mergeObjects` operator will take the last value of the document as above mentioned.

Thus, it needs to have **second `$group` stage for `$mergeObjects`** as the documents returned after the first `$group` stage are with a unique `_id` (non-duplicate `name`).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "min": {
        "$min": "$numericProperty"
      },
      "max": {
        "$max": "$numericProperty"
      },
      "avg": {
        "$avg": "$numericProperty"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "numericProperty": {
        "$mergeObjects": {
          "min": "$min",
          "max": "$max",
          "avg": "$avg"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (dual `$group` stages)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G3RukcvRPQr)